# Two Portal User Attribute filter. Is it possible?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-portal

Hi so I created a portal app in PowerApps.

I have a List in the portal, and I need to filter that list with external_client and internal_client fields. That being said, I need to use "Two" filter condition. Is it possible to do in the portals? if yes how? if no, any recommendations for workaround?

The image attached is to show you where did I configure my filter conditions in portal management and as you can see, it only allow me to put one.

[Filter condition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbgtL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can create view with group filter which will have multiple conditions set there and use this view for your entity list